# What is the "features" column on Google play when creating app releases?

Tags: android, google-play

[image: ,]

I could not find an answer anywhere online or on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this link, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features

I think it refers to the # of specs that you are using, for example if you are using the camera that's one feature and so on.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hardware requirements. For instance:

```
android.hardware.bluetooth, 
android.hardware.bluetooth_le, 
android.hardware.faketouch, 
android.hardware.location, 
android.hardware.screen.portrait, 
android.hardware.wifi
```